# Q: Mopidy-spotify starts but cannot use it via phone or laptop

Tags: debian

I have set up my mopidy with mopidy-spotify extension, to that I can plug my server into a set of speakers to use them as remote speakers. When I launch server it says, it succeeded in logging into spotify in online and offline mode. When I try to play the music via spotify on another device the server doesn't show up on remote play menu. I do have spotify premium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spotify has not opened up their Spotify Connect protocol, thus Mopidy-Spotify does not support Spotify Connect, ref. https://github.com/mopidy/mopidy-spotify/issues/14.

To control your Mopidy server, use an MPD client or one of the many web clients that have been made for Mopidy. See the Mopidy docs for

Also, you might have more success with getting help with your Mopidy installation in Mopidy's forums at https://discuss.mopidy.com.

Disclaimer: I'm a core dev of Mopidy and the dev of pyspotify and Mopidy-Spotify.

Comment: Yeah, I have just read this in the documentation and came here to close the topic. Don't You know if there is any extension that would work with spotify connect? Thanks for the answer anyway :)